# django custom widget & field as multiple buttons for in wizard form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Am trying to build something in a customized matter whereby am trying to use the custom fields and custom widget to achieve my goal. But unfortunately I cannot find enough documentation to guide me through...

In my case, am trying to build the first form of a wizard, the first form will consist of a single field which am passing choices dictionary pre-populated from the database. The dictionary will look something like this

```
    choices = {
       1 : {
            'display_name'  : 'Bronze',
            'description'  : 'this package contain all the cool features and much more.',
            },
       2 : {
            'display_name'  : 'Silver',
            'description'  : 'this package contain all the cool features and much less.',
            },
    }
```

The dictionary as seen contain the services provided dynamically from the database which will be fed to the field on initializing. On the other hand, I need to build a custom field and widget that would populate the following HTML

```
    <div class="choices">
        <div class="span3">
            <h2>Bronze</h2>
            <p>
                this package contain all the cool features and much more.
            </p>
            <input type="button" name="Bronze" value="1" />
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            <h2>Silver</h2>
            <p>
                this package contain all the cool features and much less.
            </p>
            <input type="button" name="Silver" value="2" />
        </div>            
    </div>
```

Whereby each span3 represents a row with package description name and button to select and move to the next step in the wizard. On the other hand, I tried to build a simple custom field as following

```
class PackageField(forms.CharField):
    default_error_messages = {
        'not_valid_package': _(u'Package selected is not a valid package.'),
    }

    def to_python(self, value):
        print value
        if value in self.validators:
            return None
        return value
```

and widget.py

```
class PackageWidget(MultiWidget):
    _choices = ()
    def __init__(self, choices, attrs=None):
        self._choices = choices
        super(PackageWidget, self).__init__(attrs)


    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):

        output = []

        for k, v in self._choices:
            output.append('<div class="span3">%s<input type="button" class="btn"/></div>' % v)

        return mark_safe(self.format_output(output))
```

but am sure there is a lot of mistake with the way I wrote the custom field and widget because they are throwing errors.

I would appreciate if someone can guide me in the right direction as for how to write a correct custom field & widget, if someone can pass me a reference where i can read more it would help a lot.

Comment: So what does your Form look like?  Or are you just rendering a Widget?

Comment: My form is only containing this single field rendered with its widget.. It doesn't contain much..

Answer (score 0):

How about this.  Sorry, renamed a bit but you should be able to figure out the differences.  Next time you should paste the error you're having and such.

Also, I don't know that you need a `MultiWidget` here.  Wouldn't a normal `Widget` work? I think a `MultiWidget` is for when you want to have multiple different widgets shown.

```
class Ex1Widget(forms.MultiWidget):
    _choices = ()
    def __init__(self, choices, attrs=[]):
        self._choices = choices
        super(Ex1Widget, self).__init__(attrs)


    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        output = []

        for k, v in self._choices:
            output.append('<div class="span3">%s: <input type="submit" class="btn" value="x" /></div>' % v)

        return mark_safe(self.format_output(output))

class Ex1Form(forms.Form):
    test = forms.CharField(label="", widget=Ex1Widget(choices=(('this', 'This'), ('that', 'That'), ('other', 'Other Thing'),)))
```